# Angular 2: Dynamic component's Event Emitter subscription, need to unsubscribe?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am creating a `component` dynamically and subscribing to one of its `@Ouput` `EventEmitter`.

The relevant code:

Dynamic Component:

```
 export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit {
    @Output() results: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
 ...
 }
```

Parent Component:

```
 private loadDynamicComponent(): void {
   const componentFactory = this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
   const componentRef = this.host.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);

   (<DynamicComponent>componentRef.instance).results.subscribe(result => {
       this.result = result;
   })
 }
```

I am confused about whether or not I need to `unsubscribe` or will `Angular` clean this up?

Comment: I'm surprised you are even getting any results. I didn't think you could actually subscribe to events. Are you sure your implementation is correct?

Comment: Yes, it is working. After a bit of digging around I found this was the way to handle dynamic component's @Ouput().

Comment: Ok. There is no need to unsubscribe from events nor promises as they execute once and then they're gone with the wind. You only need to be concerned about what when using Observables.

Comment: Actually that is an Observable and it never completes...

Comment: You only need the result when OnInit is called? In that case why not just use the first() operator and grab whatever value that comes first?

Comment: Yes, I only needed that result once, first() will complete the observable. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if you need to unsubscribe but just in case i do take(1) that completes the observable.

```
  confirmDialogRef.instance.buttonClicked
    .take(1)
    .subscribe(val => {
      this.appRef.detachView(confirmDialogRef.hostView);
      resolve(val);
    });
```